# fetch httponly cookie persistence through app closures

Tags: react-native, authentication, cookies, httponly

I am currently using httponly cookie based authentication to authenticate users through a website. On top of this I am creating a react native app which also has to authenticate users, ideally through the same endpoint. At this point users are able to log in through the app and the cookie is correctly send on each subsequent request using `credentials: 'include'` **(fetch)**. However, if the app is restarted, the cookie does not persist.

So far my searching has led me to the following possible workarounds:

- Manage cookies manually by extracting the cookie through something like webview or react-native-cookies, saving the cookie to storage and manually adding it to each subsequent request.
- Implement a new endpoint that returns a token and have two authentication flows, one for the website and one for the app.

Have anyone been in a similar situation? Can you point me in the right direction, so not to over complicate my code base and ensure that I am not vulnerable to XSS or other token/cookie theft.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I never implemented cookie based authentication in react native. How do you handle cookies now ?  Basically the flow should be like this:

1. You authenticate with username and password.
2. Server will respond with a header "Set-Cookie: sessionIdExample=1234"
3. Next time when you make a request you should also send that cookie, meaning you have to set a header "Cookie: sessionIdExample=1234"

From your question I guess you don't manually set that cookie, so most probably the http client is doing this for you. Now when you close the app that cookie value is lost as you said. Notice that switching to a token based authentication won't help with this. So what should you do:

1. Login with username and password.
2. When you receive that session cookie persist it. You can check async-storage or the more secure react-native-keychain for persisting data.
3. For the following requests set the session cookie manually.
4. When you close the app and then open it again, check in your async-storage or keychain if you already have a cookie saved there. If so, set that cookie and everything should work fine.

Comment: Hi Christian. Thanks for taking time to answer my question. The problem is that I do not have access to the cookie value since its protected from javascript by the httponly flag. A token based approach allows me to actually read and then save the value, which is why it would be a possible solution.

You are absolutely correct that currently the underlying browser api is taking care of handling the cookie. I was hoping there was some way to hook into this and somehow persist the cookie, without knowing the value.